# How many Africans have won the UEFA Champions League?

Tags: football, champions-league

If we define an African as somebody born in Africa and playing for an African national team, how many such players have won the UEFA Champions League? We can include Madagascar in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**European Cup winners**

- [Bruce Grobbelaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Grobbelaar) (Zimbabwe<sup>1</sup>, [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_European_Cup_Final) with Liverpool)
- [Rabah Madjer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabah_Madjer) (Algeria, [1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_European_Cup_Final) with Porto)

**UEFA Champions League Winners**

- [Abedi Pele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abedi_Pele) (Ghana, [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Marseille)
- [Finidi George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finidi_George) and [Nwankwo Kanu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nwankwo_Kanu) (Nigeria, [1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Ajax)
- [Ibrahim Tanko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibrahim_Tanko) (Ghana, [1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996%E2%80%9397_Borussia_Dortmund_season) with Borussia Dortmund)
- [Samuel Kuffour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Kuffour) (Ghana, [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Bayern Munich)
- [Geremi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geremi) (Cameroon, [2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) and [2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001%E2%80%9302_Real_Madrid_C.F._season) with Real Madrid)
- [Djimi Traoré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djimi_Traor%C3%A9) (France/Mali<sup>2</sup>, [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Liverpool)
- [Samuel Eto'o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Eto%27o) (Cameroon, [2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) and [2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Barcelona, [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Inter Milan)
- [Benni McCarthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benni_McCarthy) (South Africa, [2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Porto)
- [Yaya Touré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaya_Tour%C3%A9) (Ivory Coast, [2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Barcelona)
- [Seydou Keita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seydou_Keita) (Mali, [2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) and [2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Barcelona)
- [McDonald Mariga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald_Mariga) (Kenya, [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Inter Milan)
- [Sulley Muntari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulley_Muntari) (Ghana, [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Inter Milan)
- [Didier Drogba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didier_Drogba) and [Salomon Kalou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salomon_Kalou) (Ivory Coast, [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Chelsea)
- [Michael Essien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Essien) (Ghana, [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Chelsea)
- [John Obi Mikel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Obi_Mikel) (Nigeria, [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Chelsea)
- [Achraf Hakimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achraf_Hakimi) (Spain/Morocco<sup>3</sup>, [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017%E2%80%9318_Real_Madrid_C.F._season) with Real Madrid)
- [Sadio Mane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadio_Man%C3%A9) (Senegal, [2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) with Liverpool)
- [Mohamed Salah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohamed_Salah) (Egypt, [2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_UEFA_Champions_League_Final) also with Liverpool)
- [Édouard Mendy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Mendy) (Senegal, [2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_UEFA_Champions_League) with Chelsea)

**Sources:**

- Wikipedia article [List of European Cup and UEFA Champions League winning players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_winning_players) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_winning_players&action=history)) - this Wikipedia article [was later deleted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/List_of_European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_winning_players), a version before deletion can be found [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220601135151/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_winning_players)
- UEFA website: [Africa's European Cup final history-makers](https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2203205.html) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180417133253/https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/news/newsid=2203205.html))
- [6 African players who have won the UEFA Champions League](https://trueafrica.co/lists/6-african-players-won-uefa-champions-league/) ([Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160630164608/https://trueafrica.co/lists/6-african-players-won-uefa-champions-league/))

---

<sup>1</sup>Born in South Africa, represented Zimbabwe.
<sup>2</sup>Born in France, represented Mali.
<sup>3</sup>Born in Spain, represents Morocco.

Comment: I made the answer CW on purpose, feel free to edit if further if there is some information to be added or more sources.

Comment: NOTE: Achraf Hakini was born in Spain. Also, Djimi Traore was born in France.

Comment: Also, Bruce Grobbelaar was born in South Africa.